# How to reuse existing fragment from FragmentManager instead of re-creating them again?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am using NavigationDrawer in my application and each menu item in drawer is a fragment.Whenever user chooses a menu item I replace the current fragment in the main container  with the requested one but it recreates the fragment every-time, so i updated my code to reuse the existing fragments instead of creating them again and again as content of fragments remain same. My updated code to show fragment is :

```
public void showTabFragment() {
        TabFragment Tf = (TabFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Constants.TAB_FRAGMENT);
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (Tf != null) {
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, Tf, Constants.TAB_FRAGMENT);
        } else {
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment(), Constants.TAB_FRAGMENT);
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

In above code I am trying to get fragments by Tag but it always returns null and executes the else case(new fragment).Could someone please guide me what am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the code you've shown is for one of your menu fragment? If that's the case, what is probably happening is every time you open a menu item, the container is replaced with the new fragment(say, Fragment B) with its new tag(say, TAG 'B'). So, when you try to open the previous fragment(say, Fragment A) using it's tag(TAG 'A'), it won't be there, because that's what you replaced.

One possible solution is to hold references to the fragment as they are created, in, say a hashmap, and reuse them instead.

```
private HashMap<String, Fragment> menuFragments = new HashMap<>();
public void showMenu(String fragmentID)
{
    MenuFragment fragment = menuFragments.get(fragmentID);
    if(fragment == null)
    {
        fragment = new MenuFragment(); //Create the respective menu fragment based on the ID.
        menuFragments.put(fragmentID, fragment);
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment, fragmentID);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Or you can use simply a global object a fragment.